# <a> does not work in sub menu <li> when clicked for some unknown reason?

Tags: html, css

Everything is in this fiddle...
https://jsfiddle.net/fok42hzu/

Try clicking Posts, than submenu All Posts, this should lead to https://jsfiddle.net home page, but it does not.

It is this part of a code...

```
<li class="wp-first-item"><a href="https://jsfiddle.net/" class="wp-first-item">All Posts</a></li>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Links do not work in fiddle. They do not make a http request for you. Try the same code in a local environment or on a live server and the link will work fine.